# Trying to combine entries from "news" and "events" channels

Tags: channel-entries, search

I have a big scroller in the middle of my front page that shows the latest 3 news entries whose "Front Page Feature" field is set to "Yes". Somewhere else, smaller, I display the next upcoming event whose "Front Page Feature" is set to "Yes". I'd like to combine the 3 newest added news -and- events into that big scroller.

The code to populate the scroller is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" search:front_page_feature="Yes" dynamic="no" limit="3" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
```

I wish I could set channel="news|events", but they use different fieldsets. So I wish I could do channel="news|events" and

search:front_page_feature="Yes"
search:events_front_page_feature="Yes"

But "AND" is only allowed with multiple search terms, no OR. I don't know if there will be an easy way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Quick question. Why not to use `status` instead of `custom fields`?

Comment: If setting a `status` to define front page items isn't suitable, you might use a category instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, setting the front page status using a `status` or `category` would be a good way to accomplish this.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="news|events" status="featured_on_homepage" dynamic="no" limit="3" orderby="date" sort="desc"}`

Or...

`{exp:channel:entries channel="news|events" category="(id number of category for front page entries could go here)" dynamic="no" limit="3" orderby="date" sort="desc"}`

Comment: Thanks Robson and Nick, I totally forgot about statuses and that fixes it perfectly.